# Checking if imagedata are urlencoded jpeg via regex

Tags: php, regex, image, pcre

I have the following class:

```
namespace MyApp\ImageGenerators

class ImageGen
{

  public function checkIfImageUrlEncodedJpeg($imageData)
  {
     return preg_match($someregex,$imageData);
  }

}
```

As you can see I want to set the value of the `$someregex` variable into a valid pcre regular expression where it will validate whether the provided data is a urlencoded base64Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I used the following regular expression:

`/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,\s*[A-Za-z0-9\+\/]+=*$/i`

As you can see a urlencoded data have the following parts:

```
data:^mime^;base64,^data_encoded_as_base64^
```

Where the ^mime^ is the mime of the data that are encoded into base64 format into the `^data_encoded_as_base64^`field. Keep in mind that the approach mentioned above it just checks  that the data "looks line" as a valid urlencoded jpeg image.

I would recommend in the most cases **especially** in case that these data are user-provided or api-provided to check by decoding the base64 encoded part that is actually an jpeg image.

To keep things short your code will look like:

```
 namespace MyApp\ImageGenerators

class ImageGen
{

  public function checkIfImageUrlEncodedJpeg($imageData)
  {
     return preg_match('/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,\s*[A-Za-z0-9\+\/]+=*$/i',$imageData);
  }
}
```